# Foreign character mystery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using the MVC startup template and added mvcscaffolding. Everything worked fine, when all of a sudden *some* views started displaying swedish characters wrong. For example:

The file - Edit.cshtml - consists of:

```
@model TestApp.Models.TestViewModel

<h3>Å Ä Ö</h3>
@Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
```

The partial file - _CreateOrEdit.cshtml - only consists of:

```
@model TestApp.Models.TestViewModel

<h3>Å Ä Ö</h3>
```

The result is:

```
Å Ä Ö

Ã… Ã„ Ã
```

I have no idea even where to begin. The _Layout.cshtml contains only the standard (HTML 5) template (with meta charset="utf-8") , no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can check:

Go into `File->Advanced Save Options` for the `_CreateOrEdit.cshtml` file, and double check that it has the same encoding as the `Edit.cshtml` file.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Do you have any idea why this happens? And how to prevent it from happening. (I mean that the files suddenly gets saved in another encoding)

Comment: I saw the same once on a old project that was updated from Visual Studio 2008, to 2010, but I have not had the problem that the encoding suddenly change other than that. Good to hear it solved your problem at least :)